# Can there be any extension header before Neighbor Solicitation Payload

Tags: ipv6

The IPv6 payload may like the following:

IPv6 Header -> ExtHeader -> ... -> UpperLayer Header

I use Scapy to make a packet such that:

IPv6 -> Hop-by-Hop-Option -> Neighbor Solicitation [1]

However from Sniffer, I don't see the Neighbor Advertisement response.
So I try with this kind of packet:

IPv6 -> Neighbor Solicitation [2].

Then It's work!

Just wondering, the packet format I make in [1] is invalid? So the opposite station doesn't honor it??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other station might not understand your extension headers, in which case it can not reply to them. But in general extension headers are allowed in all packets, even Neighbour Discovery.

Comment: So on the implementation view, if we got NS as the last UpperLayer payload, we shall all reply with NA?

Comment: Is there any reference I can refer? RFC4861 does not write about this part.

Comment: RFC4861 doesn't mention extension headers because it doesn't have to. They are specified in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2460#section-4 and apply to all packets.

Comment: There is also an RFC about fragmentation headers and ND: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6980